# Как задать __doc__ для функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу, чтобы передаваемый класс задавал **doc** для функции, но не выходит:

```
class A():
    """Описание класса"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def f1():
    """Рабочее описание"""

def f2(className):
    f"""{className.__doc__}"""

print(f1.__doc__)   #Рабочее описание
print(f2.__doc__)   # None
```

Можно ли вообще такое реализовать?

UPD:

Если сделать замену, то будет срабатывать только после вызова функции

```
def f2(className):
    f2.__doc__ = className.__doc__
    return className()


print(f1.__doc__)   #Рабочее описание
print(f2.__doc__)   # None
f2(A)
print(f2.__doc__)   # Описание класса
```

Comment: Черед док-строку не получится, она парсится один раз при создании функции. Вообще, похоже, что f-строки не работают как док строки. Можно тупо через `f2.__doc__ = className.__doc__` заменить.

Comment: @insolor, я так тоже пробовал, но оно срабатывает только после того, как я вызову фунцкию, а в том месте, где читается описание (где мне надо) - там None =(

Comment: Так а как вы хотите передать имя класса в функцию, не вызывая функцию? Вообще, выглядит очень странно. Какую проблему вы так пытаетесь решить? На всякий случай: [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/1365)

Comment: @insolor, ну ведь f1 отрабатывает же. А что касается f2, то если написать ***f2.__doc__ = 'eeee'***, то итог будет такой же

Comment: "ну ведь f1 отрабатывает же" - см. первый комментарий. Док-строка парсится в момент создания функции, а не в момент вызова. Это вообще не код функции с точки зрения интерпретатора, это метаданные функции. Если вам нужно заменить док строку динамически, то нужно вызывать функцию (как минимум, явно вызывать код, пишущий в поле `__doc__`)

Comment: Вообще, не понятно, каким образом у вас функция должна понять, что нужно брать докстроку из класса A, если класс A не передан как параметр. Опишите конкретную проблему/задачу, которую вы решаете.

Comment: А вы `f2.__doc__ = className.__doc__` поместите просто сразу после окончания описания функции `f2`, а не внутри самой функции. Хотя зачем это всё по-прежнему непонятно.

Comment: Можно реализовать декоратор, копирующий докстроку из указанного объекта. Но не факт что это будет работать со статическими инструментами, типа для формирования документации по коду.